# consuming rest api from springboot, architecture question

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I want to write a REST API client with springBoot MVC. The client will send request to the API for data and will show them into the browser. For example, I'll have http://example.com/showItems mapped to itemsController.show method and rendered by an item.html (thymeleaf) template.

My question is where to put the API call and how to deal with the API response.
I'm thinking about design, not just make it work. Let also imagine I want to extend to many API call returning different objects.

I'm thinking of several options:

- a WebClient inside the controller. The controller deals with API calls that return an item Object.
- the item class takes care of the API call. And maybe adapting the result for rendering. Different objects have different API calls. Maybe all have injected the same WebClient
- I create an itemService that contains a "DAO", an itemDAO that calls the API and return item Objects. Similarly to DAO repository + models.

I'm not sure which solution to adopt. Is there another common way of doing this in spring, or some other design pattern? Or what could be the pros/cons of each solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally all the business logic and any API calls should be done in the Service layer. You should configure the other service bean in the configuration class and make a call in the service layer(a proper mvc architecture) and once you get the response you can alter it based on your requirement and then return it to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches to follow a structure of MVC in spring boot
Here I have a Solution for Where You can follow This out

---

here is my file structure

**UserController** with @RestController //All Get and Post Apis Calling

**UserService** with @Service //Define Business Logic here

**UserRegistrationReqBean** @Data //for Lombok and to reduce boilerplate

**UserMaster** @Entity //For Table Schema

- **UserMasterRepo** @Repository //for Jpa Queries

  - **UserMasterDao** //interface that interact with service layer for db queries

    - **UserMasterDaoImpl** @Component //for Dao interface definitions

---

Firstly Create A controller Class (as for Example I am taking User MANAGEMENT System)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1.0")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/getUsers")
    public List<UserMaster> getUsers() {
        return userService.getUsers();
    }

    @PostMapping("/registerUser")
    public UserMaster registerUser(@RequestBody RegisterUserReqBean reqBean) {
        return userService.registerUser(reqBean);
    }

//  @PostMapping("/updateUser")
//  public UserMaster updateUser() {
//      UserMaster updatedUser = new UserMaster();
//      return updatedUser;
//  }

}
```

Once you have created controller than define its business logic in Service layer with `@Service` Annotation

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserMasterDao userMasterDao;

    public List<UserMaster> getUsers() {
        List<UserMaster> listOfUser = userMasterDao.findAll();
        return listOfUser;
    }

    public UserMaster registerUser(RegisterUserReqBean reqBean) {
        UserMaster userMaster = new UserMaster(reqBean);
        UserMaster updatedUserMaster = userMasterRepo.save(userMaster);
        return updatedUserMaster;
    }

//  public UserMaster updateUser() {
//
//  }
}
```

create A Repo class with @Repository annotation to do some db related changes

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.sample.user.entity.UserMaster;

    @Repository
    public interface UserMasterRepo extends JpaRepository<UserMaster, Integer> {
    
//you can create your own JPA queries here
    }
```

Here my repository is empty as I am using its predefined queries

than Implements entity class with `@Entity` annotation that defines the Database table schema
use **maven Lombok dependency** to reduce boilerplate code in Entity and request Bean

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name = "kd_user_master")
    public class UserMaster {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private Integer userId;
    
        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;
    
        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;
    
        @Column(name = "user_name")
        private String userName;
    
        @Column(name = "email")
        private String email;
    
        @Column(name = "mobile_number")
        private String mobileNumber;
    
        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;
    
        @Column(name = "country")
        private String country;
    
        @Column(name = "created_at")
        private Date createdAt;
    
        @Column(name = "updated_at")
        private Date updatedAt;

//this parameterized cunstructer is used for having new object of userMaster //schema so we can directly save it to db 
public UserMaster(RegisterUserReqBean reqBean) {
        super();
        this.firstName = reqBean.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = reqBean.getLastName();
        this.userName = reqBean.getUserName();
        this.email = reqBean.getEmail();
        this.mobileNumber = reqBean.getMobileNumber();
        this.password = reqBean.getPassword();
        this.country = reqBean.getCountry();
        this.createdAt = new Date();
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }
    }
```

then we will create a DAO(Data Access Object) interface and its implementing class

```
public interface UserMasterDao{

UserMaster save(userMaster user);

List<UserMaster> findAll();
}
```

its Implementing class

```
public class UserMasterDaoImpl implements UserMasterDao{

@Autowired
UserMasterRepo repo;

@Override
UserMaster save(UserMaster user){
return repo.save(user);
}


@Override
List<UserMaster> findAll(){
return repo.findAll();
}
}
```

After business Logic and database schema we need to define Request bean for post request as it not allow us to request params or we can say query params

```
@Data
public class RegisterUserReqBean {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String userName;

    private String email;

    private String mobileNumber;

    private String password;

    private String country;

    private Date createdAt;

    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

we are using this request bean in the controller class as well as in service class for user registrations

Comment: well, actually I want to CONSUME an external API, the spring application is really a client.